# When I put a number larger than 1 in my binary-to-decimal converter, I get the error startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: c#, substring

I'm trying to create a program that converts a 5 digit binary number to decimal. As it stands, the conversion works perfectly, but I'm having trouble with giving an error message if the user inputs a number larger than 1.

```
for (int i = 4; i>=0; i--)
{
    digit = txt_input.Text.Substring(i,1);
    num = Convert.ToInt32(digit);

    //If a digit is 1 or 0
    if (num <= 1)
    {
        total += num * (Math.Pow(2, x));
        x += 1;
        goahead = 1;
    }

    //If a digit is not 1 or 0
    if (num > 1)
    {
        lst_output.Items.Add("All digits must be either 1 or 0.");
        i = 10;
        goahead = 0;
    }
}
```

When the user inputs 1's or 0's the program works as intended, but when a number larger than 1 is inputted, I get the error "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string" on line 3.

If a number with more or less than 5 digits is inputted, the user gets a message saying that the number must be 5 digits long. So as far as I can tell, the problem isn't the size of the startIndex. Especially since, no matter what the user inputs, startIndex remains unchanged.

Comment: If only there was a debugger included with Visual Studio...

Comment: The first iteration of the loop, `i` is 4. If the user doesn't enter at least a 5-digit number, how could `Substring(i, 1)` possibly work? You can't say, give me the 5th character of "1" or the 5th character of "123".

Comment: As far as getting the message saying that the number must be 5 digits long, I don't see anywhere in your code that your display that message so I have no idea why you're getting that.

Comment: _"I get the error “startIndex cannot be larger than length of string” despite startIndex not being the issue"_ -- what a ridiculous statement. Frameworks, .NET or otherwise, don't go around throwing exceptions for the fun of it. If you see an exception saying that a value is a problem, then odds are overwhelmingly in favor of that value being a problem. If your exception reminds you that `startIndex` can't be larger than the length of the string, then it is practically certain you've tried to use a value for `startIndex` larger than the length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your input is `10103`.

Now pay attention to this part of the code:

```
if (num > 1)
{
    lst_output.Items.Add("All digits must be either 1 or 0.");
    i = 10;
    goahead = 0;
}
```

Why are you making `i = 10` here?

So if you input is the above string, in the first iteration you'd go into the `if` statement above, add the message to `lst_output`, then set `i` to `10`. Then you go back to the `for` loop and the `i >= 0` condition is still true so you go inside the `for` loop once again. Now your `i = 1`, but your string is of length 5.

So;

```
digit = txt_input.Text.Substring(i,1);
```

Here now you're trying to take a substring of length 1 that starts at the `index = 10`, from a string that is only 5 characters long.

Of course it would throw

> startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
>   Parameter name: startIndex.